# I'm trying to create a Xamarin cross platform Nuget package. Issue with iOS.dll generation in iOS

Tags: xamarin, dll, package, monodevelop, nuget-package

I'm trying to create a Nuget package. So i need `myproject.dll(in PCL folder), myproject.Droid.dll(in Android folder), myproject.iOS.dll(in iOS folder)` are required to target in the nuspec file. When I run/build the source project in release mode to get dlls, pakage.iOS.dll is not generated but for PCL and Android dlls are available/generated

so does anyone have a solution or procedure to do this task, if so please let me know?

I am using `VisualStudio-17` in MAC OS Sierra High.

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you creating the NuGet package?

Comment: Sorry to mention, Finally this have been solved. I have selected a wrong project template to built the nugets,

Thank you for the reply @MattWard